# AWS : nothing inserted when use copy command from s3 to redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have big data in s3 and have to move into redshift, and have one table in redshift. Since I use python, I wrote python script and use psycopg2 to connect redshift. I succeeded to connect to redshift, but I failed to insert data from s3 to redshift.
I checked dashboard in aws website and found that redshift received a query and it loads something, but it does not insert anything and the time consumed for this process is too long like over 3 minutes. There is no error log so I can't find what is the reason.

Is there any possible cause for this?

EDIT
added copy command I used.

```
copy table FROM 's3://example/2017/02/03/' access_key_id '' secret_access_key '' ignoreblanklines timeformat 'epochsecs' delimiter '\t';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the stl_load_errors table, it has the info on data load errors
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html

```
select * from stl_load_errors order by starttime desc limit 1
```

Comment: If it isn't showing up in stl_load_errors that probably means it thought it was successful. Are you sure your're looking in the right place in S3?

Comment: I alrady did and there is no log for that.

Comment: Are your bucket and cluster in the same region? If not  you need need to specify the region option. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html